# fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused) on live server godaddy. its work on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have following function which works on localhost but it does't work on live server godaddy.
It throws warning :

> fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465
>   (Connection refused)

This is my model function

```
  public function check()
    {
        $name   = 'sangram';
        $email  = 'sangram.preciseit@gmail.com';
        $phone  = '12456789';
        $message= 'testing';

        $to = 'sangram.preciseit@gmail.com';
        $sub = 'Enquiry';
        $msg="<p>Name:$name</p><p>Email: $email</p><p>Contact Number: $phone</p><p>Message: $message</p>";

        $configGmail = array();
        $configGmail['protocol']        = 'smtp';
        $configGmail['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $configGmail['smtp_port']    = '465';
        $configGmail['mailtype']        = 'html';
        $configGmail['charset']     = 'utf-8';
        $configGmail['newline']     = "\r\n";

        // new mailid chnaged on 1st-dec-2016
        $configGmail['smtp_user']    = 'emailaddress@gmail.com';
        $configGmail['smtp_pass']    = 'mypassword';

        $configGmail['wordwrap']    = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($configGmail);

        $this->email->from('emailaddress@gmail.com',"XYZ");

        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($sub);
        $msg    =   $msg;
        $this->email->message($msg);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "mail send";
        }
        else{
            echo "mail not send";
        }
    }
```

Please tell me what should i do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `ssl` from `ssl://smtp.googlemail.com`.

Change the config array , add `smtp_crypto` and set its value to `ssl`

```
    $configGmail = array();
    $configGmail['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $configGmail['smtp_host']   = 'smtp.googlemail.com';
    $configGmail['smtp_port']   = '465';
    $configGmail['mailtype']    = 'html';
    $configGmail['charset']     = 'utf-8';
    $configGmail['newline']     = "\r\n";


    $configGmail['smtp_user']    = 'emailaddress@gmail.com';
    $configGmail['smtp_pass']    = 'mypassword';
    $configGmail['smtp_crypto']  = 'ssl';  
    $configGmail['wordwrap']     = TRUE;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows same error...

Comment: In gmail allow the IMAP settings to allow sent mails to be copied to Sent folder and make sure that Allow less secure apps is turned ON for your google account.

Comment: soory for late reply but it also not working....